# How to increase visual studio load test transaction name length? currently it's truncated if more than 64 characters

Tags: visual-studio, load-testing

How to increase visual studio load test transaction name length? currently it's truncated if more than 64 characters.

Comment: I don't have a direct answer, other than to say changing the variable length in the "LoadTest2010" database doesn't seem to do it, I think this is a baked in assumption that no one would ever have a test name larger than 64 characters. Maybe a alternative approach is called for, I wonder if a different naming standard should be used all together for these types of tests.

Answer (score 1):

I think you cannot increase the size. According to the description of the [WebLoadTestTransaction table](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/slumley/archive/2010/02/12/description-of-tables-and-columns-in-vs-2010-load-test-database.aspx) in the SQL database, the name field is of type `nvarchar (64)`. Suggesting that the name size limit is a basic property of the database.

Comment: Do you know how data get inserted into this table? i mean do you know the stored procedure name?